# TextKit 2 - How to create word level NSTextElements in order to tag words in text

Tags: swift, textkit

I'm trying to create tags/labels/badges to tag certain words(actually sometimes multiple words can constitute a tag). Currently, I've added a custom NSAttributedString key that I have used to tag words with their part of speech. I want to tag these words with a rounded background coloring. I've gone through the code in [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/textkit/using_textkit_2_to_interact_with_text) sample code, that creates tags like this:

[image: TextKit2 Paragraph Elements]

But the example code just takes existing NSTextElements(paragraph level) and applies styling to them. When I plug into the same delegate functions from the text code all the text elements are paragraph level. For example

```
This is one.
This is two.
```

Would create two text elements: `This is one.` and `This is two.`. I'm curious how I can split these into multiple text elements. For example if I wanted to just tag `EGG` in `EGG SANDWICH NO. 2`, I'm guessing I need to split that text element into two(EGG and SANDWICH NO. 2), but I can't figure out how to do that currently, or find any examples of adding word tags to text on MacOS(The app does not need to support iOS, only MacOS).

Am I along the right track for accomplishing this? If so, what's the best way to split up the NSTextElements?

Comment: Has the problem been solved? I have the same question :(

Comment: a workaround would be to go to paragraph level, then measure the offset to the beginning of a specific word (by measuring the width of the NSAttributedString). I tried it and it kind of works, but this is a headache and I can't tell how reliable it is. That's why I decided to continue with TextKit 1 where I can operate on glyphs and bounding rects of specific words with attributes... Unless we get access to something like `NSWordElement`, TextKit 2 will be useless in many cases or full of workarounds.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem and failed in a way that I really discourage to do that.

TextKit 2 is evolving. I report on trying to create a NSTextElement subclass below the NSTextParagraph level in macOS Ventana (autumn 2022).

My problem was to communicate the layout position of a text attachment, which is part of the attributed string, to the text view to position the associated subview and its exclusion path accordingly - a standard problem for text with figures.

The path to introduce a subclass of an NSTextElement into the text layout process is via delegates.

Starting at the text store:
`NSTextContentStoreDelegate` offers methods to introduce custom `NSTextElements` depending on the content of the `NSAttributedString`:

**1. Paragraph Level:**

```
func textContentStorage(NSTextContentStorage, textParagraphWith: NSRange) -> NSTextParagraph?
```

**2. Arbitrary NSTextElement Level:**

```
func textContentManager(NSTextContentManager, textElementAt: NSTextLocation) -> NSTextElement?
```

`NSTextLayoutManagerDelegate` can deliver custom `NSTextLayoutFragment` objects for these custom `NSTextElements`:

```
 func textLayoutManager( _ textLayoutManager: NSTextLayoutManager, textLayoutFragmentFor location: NSTextLocation, in textElement: NSTextElement) -> NSTextLayoutFragment
```

The custom NSTextLayoutFragment objects can do what you desire.

I tried to subclass on the `NSTextElement` level (using method 2 of `NSTextContentStoreDelegate`) and used a custom `NSTextLayoutFragment` to execute my code. The result was that the entire layout process stopped when this custom `NSTextLayoutFragment` object was encountered. I overrode all methods that are in the documentation of the `NSTextLayoutFragment` to catch the problem and failed. Even worse, I introduced memory problems into my code that Swift as a language should guard against. At places where I and the compiler expected a model object the executing code saw the view which displays this model object.

I finally accepted that I can not go below the paragraph level and subclassed `NSTextParagraph` and introduced this class using the first and not the second `NSTextContentStorageDelegate` method. I solved the desired atomisation down to the attachment within the subclasses. That worked immediately and brought the desired functionality in a very precise and efficient way.

Here is the NSTextParagraph subclass I use:

```
class ParItemAttachmentTextParagraph: NSTextParagraph {
   
   var attachmentRanges: Array<NSRange>
 
   init(attributedString:NSAttributedString, textContentManager: NSTextContentManager, elementRange: NSTextRange?, attachmentRanges ranges:Array<NSRange>) {
      attachmentRanges = ranges
      super.init(attributedString: attributedString)
      self.textContentManager = textContentManager
      self.elementRange = elementRange
   }
   
}
```

This class is introduced into the layout process by a NSTextContentStorageDelegate:

```
class TextContentStorageDelegate: NSObject, NSTextContentStorageDelegate {
   
   var attachmentRanges: Array<NSRange> = []
   
   // Returning a ParItemAttachmentTextElement if there is a ParagraphItemAttachment in the text range
   func textContentStorage(_ textContentStorage: NSTextContentStorage, textParagraphWith range: NSRange) -> NSTextParagraph? {
      if let attributedString = textContentStorage.attributedString {
         self.attachmentRanges = Array()
         attributedString.enumerateAttribute(.attachment, in: range) { (attachment: Any?, characterRange:NSRange, stopIt: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) in
            if let _ = attachment as? ParagraphItemAttachment2 {
               self.attachmentRanges.append(characterRange)
            }
         }
         if !self.attachmentRanges.isEmpty {
            let textElementAttributedString = attributedString.attributedSubstring(from: range)
            let textRange = textContentStorage.textRange(from: range)
            let parItemTextElement = ParItemAttachmentTextParagraph(attributedString: textElementAttributedString, textContentManager: textContentStorage, elementRange: textRange, attachmentRanges: self.attachmentRanges)
            return parItemTextElement
         }
      }
      return nil
   }
```

The NSTextLayoutManager reacts to the detection of this type of paragraph via ist NSTextLayoutManagerDelegate:

```
class TextLayoutManagerDelegate: NSObject, NSTextLayoutManagerDelegate {
   
   func textLayoutManager( _ textLayoutManager: NSTextLayoutManager, textLayoutFragmentFor location: NSTextLocation, in textElement: NSTextElement) -> NSTextLayoutFragment {
      
      if let parItemTextElement = textElement as? ParItemAttachmentTextParagraph {
         return ParItemAttachmentLayoutFragment(textElement: parItemTextElement, range: parItemTextElement.elementRange)
      }
      return NSTextLayoutFragment(textElement: textElement, range: textElement.elementRange)
   }
   
}
```

and introduces a special NSTextLayoutFragment - ParItemAttachmentLayoutFragment

Here is the ParItemAttachmentLayoutFragment:

```
class ParItemAttachmentLayoutFragment: NSTextLayoutFragment {
   
   var frameChangeSubscriber : Cancellable? = nil
   
   init(textElement:ParItemAttachmentTextParagraph, range:NSTextRange?) {
      super.init(textElement: textElement, range: range)
      
      let frameChangePublisher = self.publisher(for: \.layoutFragmentFrame, options: [.new])
      
      let frameChangeSubscriber = frameChangePublisher.throttle(for: .seconds(1), scheduler: RunLoop.main, latest: true).sink(receiveValue: {[weak self] newFrame in
         if let layoutFragment = self {
            Task { @MainActor () -> Void in
               layoutFragment.textViewController?.updateSubiewLocations(layoutFragment.paragraphItemPersistentIDs, layoutFragment: layoutFragment)
            }
         }
      })
      self.frameChangeSubscriber = frameChangeSubscriber
      
   }
   
   required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
      super.init(coder: coder)
   }
   
   deinit {
      self.frameChangeSubscriber?.cancel()
   }

   
   var textView: ParagraphNSView? {
      get {
         return self.textLayoutManager?.textContainer?.textView as? ParagraphNSView
      }
   }
   
   var textViewController: ParagraphNSViewController? {
      get {
         return self.textView?.viewController
      }
   }
   
   var paragraphItemAttachments: Array<ParagraphItemAttachment2> {
      get {
         var parItemAttachments: Array<ParagraphItemAttachment2> = Array()
         if let textElement = self.textElement as? ParItemAttachmentTextParagraph {
            let attributedString = textElement.attributedString
            let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length)
            attributedString.enumerateAttribute(.attachment, in: range) { (attachment: Any?, characterRange:NSRange, stopIt: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) in
               if let parItemAttachment = attachment as? ParagraphItemAttachment2 {
                  parItemAttachments.append(parItemAttachment)
               }
            }
         }
         return parItemAttachments
      }
   }
   
   var paragraphItemPersistentIDs: Array<PersistentIdentifier> {
      get {
         let parItemAttachments = self.paragraphItemAttachments
         let theParItems = parItemAttachments.compactMap({
            return $0.persistentIdentifier
         })
         return theParItems
      }
   }

   
}
```

This layout fragment calls a method to reposition its associated subviews as soon as the layout fragment changes its frame:

```
updateSubiewLocations(layoutFragment.paragraphItemPersistentIDs, layoutFragment: layoutFragment)
```

You see - this is complex and really embedded into my use case. Difficult to use directly - but you get the idea.

Comment: would you have a code sample on how you customized NSTextParagraph? There doesn't seem to be anything in there that generates NSTextLayout or LineFragments. Was wondering how you tied everything up together. Thanks

Comment: I added a code example (see above)